# Vector of Substrings of Character Vector With Base R

Tags: r, string, subset

I have the vector

```
v <- c("abc","def","ghi")
```

Is it possible to subset with *substring* or *substr* to get a vector with the first and third characters of every element?

```
#desired output: "ac","df","gi"
```

My attempts produce a vector with alternating substrings.

```
substring(v,first=c(1,3),last=c(1,3))
#output: "a" "f" "g"
```

If it can't be done with *substring* or *substr* and vector subsetting, is there a base R solution for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably using two `substring` or `substr`

```
paste0(substring(v, 1, 1), substring(v, 3, 3))
#[1] "ac" "df" "gi"
```

Or another base R solution using regex

```
sub("(.).(.)", "\\1\\2", v)
#[1] "ac" "df" "gi"
```